# Display dynamic value in label in pyglet

Tags: python, user-interface, pyglet

I am newbie trying to develop GUI using python. My data is a .sgy file and I need to display graphs as output. I have chosen Pyglet to do so.Is that a right choice? I am struck in the first step itself where by I want to display the header of the seismic data in a label in the window. Here is the code that I have tried:

```
import pyglet      
import sys     
import numpy as np            #package for numerical processing    
import matplotlib             #package for plotting graphs    
import obspy                  #package for reading sgy file   
import pandas                 #package for handling csv file   
from obspy.io.segy.segy import _read_segy    
from obspy.core.util import get_example_file    


window = pyglet.window.Window()    

filename = get_example_file("/home/khyati/Downloads/FindTrappedMiners.SGY")   

st = _read_segy(filename)    

for i in st.traces:    
    label = pyglet.text.Label(i,   
                          font_name='Times New Roman',    
                          font_size=36,   
                          x=window.width//2,   
                          y=window.height//2,   
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')   


@window.event    
def on_draw():    
    window.clear()    
    label.draw()    

pyglet.app.run()
```

And here is the error that I am encountering

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)    
<ipython-input-32-869a2d62b820> in <module>()    
     21                           x=window.width//2,   
     22                           y=window.height//2,    
---> 23                           anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')   
     24    
     25 

/home/khyati/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet-1.2.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/text/__init__.py in __init__(self, text, font_name, font_size, bold, italic, color, x, y, width, height, anchor_x, anchor_y, align, multiline, dpi, batch, group)    
    428    
    429         '''    
--> 430         document = decode_text(text)   
    431         super(Label, self).__init__(document, x, y, width, height, 
    432                                     anchor_x, anchor_y,    

/home/khyati/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet-1.2.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/text/__init__.py in decode_text(text)   
    210     '''   
    211     decoder = get_decoder(None, 'text/plain')     
--> 212     return decoder.decode(text)  
    213   
    214 class DocumentLabel(layout.TextLayout):    

/home/khyati/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet-1.2.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/text/formats/plaintext.py in decode(self, text, location)   
     44     def decode(self, text, location=None):   
     45         document = pyglet.text.document.UnformattedDocument()    
---> 46         document.insert_text(0, text)   
     47         return document    

/home/khyati/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet-1.2.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/text/document.py in insert_text(self, start, text, attributes)    
    422     
    423         '''    
--> 424         self._insert_text(start, text, attributes)    
    425         self.dispatch_event('on_insert_text', start, text)   
    426       

/home/khyati/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet-1.2.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/text/document.py in _insert_text(self, start, text, attributes)     
    426       
        427     def _insert_text(self, start, text, attributes):    
    --> 428         self._text = u''.join((self._text[:start], text, self._text[start:]))     
        429         len_text = len(text)    
        430         for element in self._elements:     

    TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, SEGYTrace found
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: read error message: what is `i` ? Some trace. What is trace ? Not string. But  Label need string as first argument. So maybe you need `str(i)` or maybe it has `i.text` or somthing similar.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ObsPy documentation](https://docs.obspy.org/master/packages/obspy.io.segy.html) there's a `stats` value of every element in `st`.

Since `st` in itself appears to be a array of data, and you're simply extracting the ID of each data, you have two or three options.

One, would be if you want to print the ID as a graphical label, then do what @furas said:

```
for i in st.traces:
    label = pyglet.text.Label(str(i),
                      x=window.width//2,
                      y=window.height//2,
                      anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
```

Or, you can extract the data you want to show via two options:

```
label = pyglet.text.Label(st.traces[i].data, ...)
```

or

```
label = pyglet.text.Label(st[i].stats.segy.trace_header, ...)
```

Either way, your main problem is that [pyglet.text.Label](https://pythonhosted.org/pyglet/api/pyglet.text.Label-class.html) takes `str` as it's `text` parameter. There for you canẗ insert an integer as the first parameter. Either convert your int or use the data in the trace file that is a text representation.

Also note that by doing `for i in x: label = <insert label>` you're replacing the label on each loop, and you're doing this outside of your `on_draw()` function, which means you'll only create one label essentially. Maybe you've already figured this out or it's on purpose, but worth mentioning.

Disclaimer: I've never worked with *obspy*, I've just worked a lot with Pyglet, so maybe someone more experienced with obspy will correct me on the use of this data.

Comment: Thank you for the help but on using either of the way that you mentioned, I am getting certain error like on using the second method, the error that was encountered is:                         TypeError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-612977782bf1> in <module>()
     14 
     15 for i in st.traces:
---> 16         label = pyglet.text.Label(st[i].stats.segy.trace_header,
     17                           font_name='Times New Roman',
     18                           font_size=36,
TypeError: 'SEGYFile' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Also since I am completely new in programming with Python, I want to know whether moving forward with Pyglet is a good option or not? I need to develop very complex GUIs. Is there any other way to develop GUI,something that includes drag and drop widgets like Visual Studio has. Thanxx in advance!

Comment: Are you using my code? And are you running it through some sort of IDE? Because the error output (traceback) looks kinda funky to me. It depends on what sort of UI you're trying to do. I would say if you just want buttons and labels, you're better of with wxPython or whatever library you feel is fancy enough. But this is a question not really suited for stackoverflow (what UI library to use) since we don't usually allow opinion-based questions. I can help you with this particular problem tho. But what code did you use, because I never used `getitem`. Unless `trace_header`, but full stack plase

Comment: @KhyatiAgrawal Forgot to tag you and I ran out of characters in my message. Check the above message.

Comment: Yes I used your code and have no idea what went wrong. Amyway thanx for the help I think i would better move forward with IronPython as the UI that I need to develop is very tough including graphs and 3d outputs. So I would be more comforatble with developing UI with C#